# R help files on different OS

Tags: r, operating-system

Is there some way to access the Windows version of a helpfile on a Linux computer within R?

I write a decent amount of R code on my Linux machine, but I do have to make sure the code will run on a Windows machine for collaborators.

I've been burned a number of times by reading a help file on my Linux machine, writing my code, and then spending hours wondering why it's not working on the Windows machine until I check the helpfile *on that machine* and realise that it is different to the one on the Linux machine.

It'll usually have a "NOTE: On Windows, xxxx behaves differently...", and I wish I knew that while I was writing the code on my Linux machine!

I do realise that many help files are system-specific (for example `?system`), but sometimes I would like to read the Windows version on my Linux computer. Today I found myself wanting to read `?windows` but had to boot up my Windows laptop just to read that helpfile, because that function isn't available on Linux and so there's no help file.

cheers.

Comment: An alternative to Dirk's suggestion would be to keep of a copy of the Windows version of the R Reference Index on your Linux machine. It's a single huge pdf containing the help files for all of the base R packages, and is stored in `$R_HOME/doc/manual/refman.pdf`.  You could also investigate the possibility of copying over [part of] a Windows install of R onto your Linux box, and then using the `lib.loc` argument to `help()` to direct your search for help files to the Windows install's directory tree. That seems like more hassle than its worth, but its up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always look at the source which gives you clear conditionals -- this is from `man/system.Rd`:

```
#ifdef windows
  Only double quotes are allowed on Windows: see the examples.  (Note: a
  Windows path name cannot contain a double quote, so we do not need to
  worry about escaping embedded quotes.)

  [...]

#endif
#ifdef unix
  Unix-alikes pass the command line to a shell (normally \file{/bin/sh},
  and POSIX requires that shell), so \code{command} can be anything the
  shell regards as executable, including shell scripts, and it can
  contain multiple commands separated by \code{;}.

  [...]

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks like what I might have to do. It's a shame, though.